# Cannot use Pillow in my Python project

Tags: python, installation, pip, python-imaging-library

I recently installed pip, and used that to install Pillow, the Python imaging library, on Ubuntu 14.04. When I write some simple code like the following:

```
import sys

from PIL import Image

im= Image.open('path/to/image.jpg')
im.save('path/to/image2.jpg')
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/path/to/test.py", line 3, in <module>
from PIL import Image
File "/path/to/test.py", line 3, in <module>
from PIL import Image
ImportError: cannot import name Image
```

I have also tried just 'import Image', but this doesn't work either. I seem to recollect that this vaguely worked once, before I installed Pillow. It seems as though nobody else has this problem, so is there something I'm missing? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: is `import PIL` working?

Comment: Any chance you have two Python versions (or two installations of the same version), and installed pip and Pillow with one of them, but then tried to use Pillow with the other one? Try `print(sys.path)` from Python, then `cat $(which pip)` from the shell.

Comment: @misspec Yes, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @abarnert What should I be looking for here? Should I copy and paste the results?

Comment: @FinMoorhouse: Just paste them here. (Also, if you know or suspect you have multiple Python installations, please tell us.) If `import PIL` worked, there's a good chance that this isn't the problem, but it can't hurt to rule it out.

Comment: Meanwhile, if `import PIL` works, try `import PIL; print(PIL.__file__)`. If it gives you some path like `/foo/bar/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py`, then `ls /foo/bar/site-packages/PIL`. If it gives something different… tell us what it gives, I guess. Oh, also: Any chance you installed old-fashioned PIL before installing modern Pillow? Even if you did, Pillow _should_ replace it cleanly, but… again, rule everything out.

Comment: @abarnert import PIL; print(PIL.__file__) gives /home/fin/PIL.py
/home/fin/PIL.py. I don't remember manually installing PIL before Pillow.

Comment: did you create a file `PIL.py`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, it was the name I gave to the file which i was working in (stupidly)

Comment: @FinMoorhouse, you are not the first and won't be the last ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham What can i say! Does this lead to a solution in any way?

Comment: @FinMoorhouse, what happens if you rename your file?

Comment: @abarnert The problem persists- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fin/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ImportError: cannot import name Image

Comment: what does `PIL.__file__` output now?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Aha! I deleted the PIL.py file that I thought I had already deleted and suddenly everything works. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Summrising the answer in the comments, for future reference]

Make sure you haven't created a file called PIL.py (or PIL.pyc), as this will interfere with the import.

To check:

`import PIL;
    print(PIL.__file__)`

This should give you some path like `/foo/bar/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py`. and not something like `/home/fin/PIL.py`.